# How to get place name from mapkit

Tags: swift, xcode

Hello guys can you please tell me how should I get place name when I drop pin on mapview? this is my code

```
      let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: touchedCoordination.latitude, longitude: touchedCoordination.longitude)

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            var placeMark : CLPlacemark!
            placeMark = placemarks![0]
            print(placeMark.name)
            print(placeMark.subAdministrativeArea)
            print(placeMark.thoroughfare)
```

and for example when I drop pin on McDonald's it prints :

```
Optional("10990 N Stelling Rd")
Optional("Santa Clara")
Optional("N Stelling Rd")
```

but I want to print McDonald's for place name not "10990 N Stelling Rd"

thanks for your help ;)

Comment: have you checked `placeMark.areasOfInterest`?

Comment: @MarcelT yes that’s nil idk why 

Comment: When you see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418171/5227674) it says, that it should be in that array. Did you try another CLLocation?

Comment: @MarcelT yes I know that’s an array for that reason i said idk why that is nil, no i did not try another another cllocation

Comment: Try another CLLocation e.g. from another MCDonalds probably you are able to see the name there. Then for the specific location you are currently trying, Apple has not the data quality you need for your case. Then you should try another Geocoding service e.g. nominatim or google.

Comment: @MarcelT thank you Marcel i will do that ✌